# Exclusive processes, running into a virtual desktop in MACOSX

Tags: macos, parallel-processing, desktop, quartz-graphics, osx-leopard

the problem here it's that I need to run one process inside an Instance of a virtual desktop on MACOSX snow leopard. But for example when I make a test on SPACES which is the default desktop manager wich comes with MACOSX I realize that  processes are shared between the desktops, so eventually I could kill any process running inside the other desktops, lets say desktop number 01, from the root desktop. But I would like that my process only could be executed or launched into the virtual desktop that I choose, while the root desktop it's unable to see it or interact with it in any way.
I know that in Microsoft windows this its perfectly reachable, so i think that in MACOSX it could be too.

any idea? 
its there some guidelines in order to get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after a lot of work and testing, I found one good way to reach my objective. I found chroot similar to jails in Linux so I can make space inside macos to host a new operating system but not equal to virtual machines do. so i can have my own exclusive space to control some processes and files and folders and everithing I need to run in an exclusive way inside the host system.
additionally I can use X11 to execute graphical applications.

for now this is useful for my problem I tried to resolve here.